# Using nested loops

Tags: java, loops

I'm really struggling to do this! `z` is an array of gravitational fields. To find the total gravitational field acting on a planet, say earth, I want to add all the entries together, while excluding the entry for earth's gravitational field, because earth's gravity doesn't act on earth itself.

For example, say `z = [earthGrav, sunGrav, marsGrav, moonGrav]`. Then the total field on earth is `sunGrav+ marsGrav + moonGrav`. I could maybe deal with this by using `s=i+1`. But that doesn't work subsequently, for the sun, when `sunGrav = earthGrav+marsGrav+moonGrav`, because the first entry would be left out!

```
for(int i=0; i<planets.length;i++){     
    for(int s=0;s<z.length;s++){
        if(i!=s){
            sum1.increaseBy(z[s]); 
            newP[i] = planets[i].updatePosition(position[i], velocity[i], timeStep, sum1);
        }
        else{
            sum1.scale(1);  
        }
    }
}
```

Problem is, the way I've done it above means whenever I add 1 to `i`, 1 also gets added to `s`, so `s` and `i` are always the same and the if statement never gets executed! Can anyone think of a way to do this?

Comment: It's not true that i and s are always the same.

Comment: How are you finding `i!=s` to be insufficient to exclude the current planet? (Also, do you want to zero out the sum between planets?)

Comment: @user Then I've misunderstood how loops work. I thought that it would set i=0, then s=0, so i=s and the else statement is executed. Then I've said i++, so i=1 now, and s++, so s=1 now, and again s and i are equal.

Comment: @AndyThomas The output is wrong, and I assumed it stemmed from here. What does zero out the sum mean?

Comment: *Then I've said i++, so i=1 now, and s++, so s=1 now* That's wrong, It executes `s++` first, and when that inner `for-loop` has finished then and only then it does `i++`

Comment: @Karacoreable Every time you loop around, you are increasing `sum1` (which I assume is the total field for a given planet) without resetting it first. This means that after your first iteration of the inner loop is done, all subsequent loops will include the total field for that first planet as well as the sum of all fields for the current planet, and the third planet will include the fields of the 1st and 2nd, and so on... To avoid this, you could include a `sum1 = 0;` (or equivalent method) before the start of your inner loop to make sure it always starts at zero.

Comment: Can you provide what `planets`, `z` and `sum1` look like? (Add any method you might have). And what's your actual output and the desired output?

Comment: Not a solution, but advice...  You're doing two completely unrelated things in one method: filtering inputs, and then doing something with whatever inputs remain.  That should be _two_ methods.  Each task will be easier to write and to understand when it's not tangled in the other.