# Follow-up: nested loops and arrays

Tags: java, arrays, loops

[Using nested loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34047828/using-nested-loops?noredirect=1#comment55852829_34047828)

I'm still trying to achieve the same thing stated in the question above. Basically my code now looks like this:

```
for(int ac = 0; ac < gravityObject.length; ac++){
        gravField[ac].setVector(0,0);
        System.out.println(ac);
        for(int ad=0;ad<gravityObject.length;ad++){
            System.out.println(ad);
            if(ac!=ad){
                gravField[ac].increaseBy(gravityObject[ac].aDueToGravity(planetMass[ad], position[ad], position[ac]));
            }
            else{
                //do nothing
            }
            gravField[ac].print();
        }
    }
```

This is very annoying, and I don't understand why it's happening!

EXAMPLE:
I want to calculate the acceleration of the earth due to the sun and the moon. So I have double[] planetMass = {earthMass, sunMass, moonMass}, an array of particle objects Particle[] planets = {earth, sun, moon} and an array of the accelerations due to gravity they experience, which are yet to be calculated:
PhysicsVector[] gravField = {earthGrav,sunGrav,moonGrav}.

My loop is meant to fill this array. I want to sum sunGrav and moonGrav to find acceleration of earth, and store the result in earthGrav, so in gravField[0]. Then earthGrav+moonGrav, and this should be stored as gravField[1].

My loop correctly calculates the values of gravField[0], gravField[1] and gravField[2], then unfortunately sets all gravField[] equal to gravField[2].

This is presumably because I keep resetting gravField[ac] to zero. But if I don't, then I don't get correct values. Rest of my main class(the problem is definitely the loop though):
    public static PhysicsVector[] copyArray(PhysicsVector[] a) {
        int length = a.length;
        PhysicsVector[] copy = new PhysicsVector[length];
        System.arraycopy(a, 0, copy, 0, length);
        return copy;
    }

```
public static double sumArray(double[] p){
    double sum = 0;
    for(int z= 0; z < p.length; z++){
        sum += p[z];
    }
    return sum;
}

public static PhysicsVector[] subtract(PhysicsVector[] diff, PhysicsVector g){
    for (int ab=0; ab<diff.length;ab++){ 
        diff[ab].decreaseBy(g);
    }
    return diff;
}   
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{

    java.io.File file = new java.io.File("output.txt" );
    java.io.PrintWriter n = new PrintWriter(file);

    //Initialise variables here
    PhysicsVector earthInitialPos = new PhysicsVector();
    PhysicsVector earthInitialV = new PhysicsVector();
    PhysicsVector sunInitialV = new PhysicsVector();
    PhysicsVector sunInitialPos = new PhysicsVector();
    PhysicsVector moonInitialPos = new PhysicsVector();
    PhysicsVector moonInitialV=new PhysicsVector();

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);       
    System.out.println("Please enter the size of the time step:");
    double timeStep = scanner.nextDouble();

    //SET PLANETS' INITIAL POSITIONS
    //Set Earth's initial position and initial velocity
    earthInitialPos.setVector(1.4960*Math.pow(10,11),0);
    earthInitialV.setVector(0,29785.5889);
    //Set the sun's initial position
    sunInitialPos.setVector(0,0);
    sunInitialV.setVector(0,-0.08945);      //v = 2*pi*R/T
    //Set the moon's initial position and velocity
    moonInitialPos.setVector(3.844*Math.pow(10,8),0);
    moonInitialPos.increaseBy(earthInitialPos);
    moonInitialV.setVector(0,1023.2195);
    moonInitialV.increaseBy(earthInitialV);

    //CREATE GRAVFIELD OBJECTS
    GravField sunGravField = new GravField(sunMass, sunRadius, sunInitialPos);
    GravField earthGravField = new GravField(earthMass, earthRadius, earthInitialPos);
    GravField moonGravField = new GravField(moonMass, moonRadius, moonInitialPos);

    //CREATE PARTICLE OBJECTS   
    Particle earth = new Particle(earthMass, earthInitialPos, earthInitialV);
    Particle sun = new Particle(sunMass, sunInitialPos, sunInitialV); 
    Particle moon = new Particle(moonMass, moonInitialPos, moonInitialV);

    double time = 0;
    double finalTime = 31557600;            //Run for one earth year

    //Initialise newV and set equal to initialV
    PhysicsVector newV = new PhysicsVector();
    newV = earthInitialV;
    PhysicsVector sunNewV = new PhysicsVector();
    sunNewV = sunInitialV;
    PhysicsVector moonNewV = new PhysicsVector();
    moonNewV = moonInitialV;

    PhysicsVector newSunGrav = new PhysicsVector();
    PhysicsVector newEarthGrav = new PhysicsVector();
    PhysicsVector newMoonGrav = new PhysicsVector();

    GravField[] gravityObject = {earthGravField, sunGravField, moonGravField};
    PhysicsVector[] position = {earthInitialPos, sunInitialPos, moonInitialPos}; 
    PhysicsVector[] velocity = {newV, sunNewV, moonNewV};
    PhysicsVector[] gravField = {zero, zero, zero};
    double[] planetMass = {earthMass, sunMass, moonMass};
    Particle[] planets = {earth, sun, moon};
    PhysicsVector a = new PhysicsVector(0,0);

    //Calculate the centre of mass and subtract position from positions of planets, so c.o.m is at origin
    PhysicsVector centreOfMass = new PhysicsVector();
    centreOfMass = earth.centreOfMass(planetMass, position);
    position = SolarSim.subtract(position, centreOfMass);

    //Calculate centre of mass velocity and subtract from planet velocities
    PhysicsVector centreOfMassVelocity = new PhysicsVector();
    centreOfMassVelocity = earth.cOMVel(planetMass, velocity);
    velocity = SolarSim.subtract(velocity, centreOfMassVelocity);

    //Calculate fields of planets
    for(int ac=0; ac<gravityObject.length; ac++){
        gravField[ac].setVector(0,0);
        System.out.println(ac);
        for(int ad=0;ad<gravityObject.length;ad++){
            System.out.println(ad);
            if(ac!=ad){
                //gravField[ac].increaseBy(gravityObject[ac].aDueToGravity(planetMass[ad], position[ad], position[ac]));
                a.increaseBy(gravityObject[ac].aDueToGravity(planetMass[ad], position[ad], position[ac]));
                gravField[ac] = a;
            }
            else{
                //do nothing
            }
            gravField[ac].print();
        }
    }

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(gravField));
    PhysicsVector[] newP = new PhysicsVector[position.length];
    PhysicsVector[] newGrav = {zero,zero,zero};
    PhysicsVector[] newVel = new PhysicsVector[velocity.length];

    PhysicsVector sum1 = new PhysicsVector(0,0);
    PhysicsVector sum2 = new PhysicsVector(0,0);
    PhysicsVector sum3 = new PhysicsVector(0,0);

    //do{
        PhysicsVector[] y = new PhysicsVector[gravField.length];
        y=copyArray(gravField);
        PhysicsVector[] z = new PhysicsVector[gravField.length];
        z=copyArray(gravField);

        for(int i=0; i<planets.length;i++){
            sum1.setVector(0,0);    
            for(int s=0;s<z.length;s++){

                if(i!=s){
                    sum1.increaseBy(z[s]); 
                }
                else{
                    sum1.scale(1);  
                }

            }
            newP[i] = planets[i].updatePosition(position[i], velocity[i], timeStep, sum1);
        }
        newP[2].increaseBy(newP[0]);
        //Calculate the centre of mass and subtract position from positions of planets, so c.o.m is at origin
        centreOfMass = earth.centreOfMass(planetMass, newP);
        newP = SolarSim.subtract(newP, centreOfMass);

        for(int j=0; j<gravityObject.length; j++){    

            for(int l=0;l<gravityObject.length;l++){

                if(j!=l){

                newGrav[j].increaseBy(gravityObject[j].aDueToGravity(planetMass[j], position[j], position[l]));
                }
                else{

                }
            }
        }

        for(int k=0; k<planets.length; k++){
            sum2.setVector(0,0);
            sum3.setVector(0,0);
            for(int m = 0; m<y.length;m++){
                if(k!=m){
                    sum2.increaseBy(y[m]);
                    sum3.increaseBy(newGrav[m]);
                }
                else{
                    sum2.scale(1);
                    sum3.scale(1);
                }
            }
            newVel[k] = planets[k].updateVelocity(velocity[k], timeStep, sum2, sum3);
        }
        newVel[2].increaseBy(newVel[0]);
        //Calculate centre of mass velocity and subtract from planet velocities
        centreOfMassVelocity = earth.cOMVel(planetMass, newVel);
        newVel = SolarSim.subtract(newVel, centreOfMassVelocity);

        gravField = copyArray(newGrav);

        time+=timeStep;

        //n.println(e+" "+z);
        //n.println(g+" "+h);

    //}while (time<=finalTime);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(newP));

    n.close();
}
```

}

Comment: What do you expect from your code?

Comment: @Abdelhak The code here: gravityObject[ac].aDueToGravity(planetMass[ad], position[ad], position[ac]      represents acceleration. I would like to sum accelerations for all ad and store them in gravField[ac].

Comment: @Abdelhak Would a more extensive example be helpful?

Comment: Try to put all your code

Comment: @Abdelhak I've added an example of what I'd like it to do, and added the rest of my main class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try zeroing out gravField in a separate step:

```
for(int ac = 0; ac < gravityObject.length; ac++){
    gravField[ac].setVector(0,0);
}

for(int ac = 0; ac < gravityObject.length; ac++){
    System.out.println(ac);
    /// the rest of your code as above, without setVector(0,0)
```

Comment: Tells me ac is already defined. Should I remove the int declaration from the second for loop, or change it to some other variable like h?

Comment: Changing it to another variable name should work, but it's odd the above should also work since "ac" should be scoped to the "for" loop. You are closing out the first "for" loop with a close curly } ?

Comment: Either way, the core idea is to zero out everything first, and then separately use your nested loops to add the acceleration values to that. Good luck!

Comment: Oh yes, I was using ) instead of }. It still doesn't work though, as in it compiles, but the loops aren't linked so it sums gravField[0] and gravField[1] and gravField[2]. To work it has to be zeroed after every run, but that means the values I need aren't stored.

Comment: Looking at your original code, it looks like you are setting all 3 members of gravField to references to the same object: PhysicsVector[] gravField = {zero, zero, zero}; Perhaps that is why they are being summed. Try setting each one to a new object, perhaps as: PhysicsVector[] gravField = {new PhysicsVector(), new PhysicsVector(), new PhysicsVector()};